# VBA Macro read user selected field names from CSV file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `sample.csv` file with four fields/columns:

- Date
- City
- State
- Amount

Below is my code which retrieves all four fields of the data:

```
Sub LoadFromFile()
    Dim fileName As String, folder As String

    folder = "d:\Sample.csv"
    fileName = ActiveCell.Value

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables _
        .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & folder & fileName, Destination:=ActiveCell)
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

My requirement is to display only three fields/columns: Date, City and Amount. How can I do that?

Comment: After importing your file, delete the third column.

Comment: hi we need to do in macro code ,not manually  delete the column

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Columns(3).Delete`

Comment: If we run the macro code from the first column of excel , then only it delete the third column .otherwise If i run the macro code from H column in excel , it display all the four fields.

Comment: you could look into QueryTable.ResultRange, it should give you which columns are used and thus you can hide that column.
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.resultrange

Answer (score 1):

```
       Sub CSVData()
        Dim con As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

        Set con = New ADODB.Connection
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

        Dim currentDataFilePath As String
        Dim currentDataFileName As String
        Dim nextRow As Integer
        Dim emptystr As String
         '"H:\projectfiles\csv\", "Book.csv"
        currentDataFilePath = ("H:\projectfiles\csv\")
        currentDataFileName = ("Book.csv")
         emptystr = "NULL"


        con.Provider = "Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0"
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & currentDataFilePath & ";" & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"""
        'MsgBox currentDataFilePath

        con.Open

        rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & currentDataFileName & "] ", con
        rs.MoveFirst
        'nextRow = Worksheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        'Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(nextRow, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

        'MsgBox rs.RecordCount
        With rs
        Do Until .EOF

        'check the field is not null before process

         If Not IsNull(rs(0)) Then
         custordernum = rs(0)
         End If

         If Not IsNull(rs(1)) Then
        ContactNAme = "" & Replace(rs(1), "'", " ")

        Else
        ContactNAme = emptystr
        End If

        If Not IsNull(rs(2)) Then
        colladd1 = "" & Replace(rs(2), "'", " ")
        Else
        colladd1 = emptystr
        End If
        MsgBox colladd1
        .MoveNext
        Loop
         End With


        rs.Close
        con.Close
        End Sub
```

Comment: please note that instead of using numbers you change the numbers to named fields like so                                                                                           `If Not IsNull(rs("Agreement")) Then
 custordernum = rs("Agreement")
 EndIf `then you can read in the fields you want like that

Comment: Please add a description to describe what your code achieves and why it is an answer.

Comment: this will read your csv file and read in any number of fields you want to use you can either use the named fields or the indexes to get the value from you record sets if the csv has no headers. and when using indexes please note that it is zero based so 1 will be your second filed

Answer (score 1):

This is your alternative doing exactly what you want so you can copy and change to your specification

```
       Sub CSVDataBok()
        Dim con As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

        Set con = New ADODB.Connection
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

        Dim currentDataFilePath As String
        Dim currentDataFileName As String
        Dim nextRow As Integer
        Dim emptystr As String
         '"H:\projectfiles\csv\", "Book.csv"
        currentDataFilePath = ("H:\resources\")
        currentDataFileName = ("Book2.csv")
         emptystr = "NULL"


        con.Provider = "Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0"
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & currentDataFilePath & ";" & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"""
        'MsgBox currentDataFilePath

        con.Open

        rs.Open "SELECT Date,City,State,Amount FROM [" & currentDataFileName & "] ", con
        rs.MoveFirst
        nextRow = Worksheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(nextRow, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

        rs.Close
        con.Close
        End Sub
```